# Unlink user/subscription licence from UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm testing a subscription functional of UWP app which is published in the Microsoft store. The subscription is free and I was able to get subscription licence for my app using Windows.Services.Store for a user without any problems.

I have a question - how can I unlink user from app to perform further tests?

I have logged out from that account, cleared app local data, reinstalled it but I'm still getting "true" while checking subscription anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question - how can I unlink user from app to perform further tests?

This is because once you acquire full license of the product on that device, even if you sign in with another account, you will still have the full license permission  on the same device, which is by design.

If you need to test the subscription product further, you might use another device and sign in with another Microsoft account for testing.

Comment: Ok, and can I cancel a free subscription myself? I can't see such button in the account and there is a suggestion to connect microsoft support to cancel it.

Comment: @E.A.P. Customers could cancel a subscription at [this page](http://account.microsoft.com/services). But you still continue to have access to the subscription for the duration of the current billing period. So, for further test scenario, you still need to use another device and sign in with another Microsoft account.